# PHP Global Variable throught pages

Tags: php, variables, global

I am using jquery throughout a php project, so all pages load dynamically into the main page, I am trying to make links only visible to a certain user, so if they goto the main page and append the URL, i.e ?mode=55rt67 this gets stored as a variable and can be checked throughout the app. I am using the below, but it doesnt work. any suggestions?

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
$mode = "user";
}else{
define ('$mode', '($_GET['mode']);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`define` is used to declare constants, you want to use a variable, not a constant.

UPDATED (use session to store mode variable):

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
    $_SESSION['mode'] = "user";
}else{
    $_SESSION['mode'] = $_GET['mode'];
}
```

And don't forget to use `session_start` on every page

Comment: But the variable isnt carried onto other pages.

Comment: If you want in other pages the cleanest way is store in session, i'll update my answer

Comment: The variable will be available within the global scope of all included files or any code within those files (outside of functions/ classes). Also, what is wrong with using a constant?

Comment: @James, there's nothing wrong with constants, but mode is not a constant itself... is variable, so, this is why i prefer to use variables. With constants need to be carefully because it cannot be redefined, so, if you use a similar code on another page, the constant will not change.

Comment: @Sal00m Completely agree. I wonder why the var isn't in scope where he needs it. Var would be better than setting an entire session for just one piece of data if they don't use sessions for anything else

Comment: How would I do this? sessions isnt working properly, getting annoyed with it now!

Comment: Learn how to use sessions here http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php, if you have problem with sessions after reading it i sugggest to  ask another question

Comment: I understand sessions, its not carrying the session through to the next page, despite using session start.

Comment: You need to use `session_start` in all your pages, and at the start of every php file

Answer (score 0):

Change your code with below code.

```
// Try this
        if(isset($_GET['mode']) ){  
           define ('mode',$_GET['mode']);
        }else{
           define ('mode',"user");
        }
    echo mode;

//OR

       if(isset($_GET['mode']) ){  
           global  $mode = $_GET['mode'];
        }else{
           global  $mode = "user";
        }
 echo $mode;
```

Comment: "Why" should they do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
if (empty($_GET)) {
    $_SESSION['mode'] = "user";
}else{
    $_SESSION['mode'] = $_GET['mode'];
}
```

The above solution worked perfectly, added session_start to the index page, and it now carries through the rest of the pages.

Awesome, thanks all